# Present nested lists into columns

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navigation

I have a nested navigation list that has a maximum depth of 3, for example:

```html
<!-- Depth 1 -->
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>
       <li>...</li>

       <!-- Depth 2 -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <li>...</li>

                <!-- Depth 3 -->
                <ul>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I want each nested level to show on hover to the right of the parent list but flush to the top of the grandparent.

So far I have this:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  width: 33.333vw;
}

nav ul>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

nav ul>li.has-children>a:after {
  content: '»';
  float: right;
}

nav ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  transition: background-color 0.4s;
}

nav ul>li>ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

nav ul>li:hover>a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

nav ul>li:hover>ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 1.1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1.2</a></li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 1.3</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.3.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 2.1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.1.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 2.2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3.4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 5.1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 5.2</a></li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 5.3</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.3.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 5.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/thelevicole/q4y8fxu0/)

But this positions the sub list to the top of the parent element which produces whitespace above.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS or will I have to to modify the DOM with javascript?

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your question meaningless. Always include your code right along with your question and if you press the stack snippet button `<>` while editing your question, you can insert your code into an executable environment, just like a Fiddle or a Pen.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for your edit, however, I have rolled the question back to its previous state because the the SO snippet editor doesn't allow for SASS pre-processing which broke the example I gave.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You'll be gald to know I've added the code inline. I hope this pleases the Gods!

Comment: If your question is not about the Sass work, you can (and should) just switch over to the compiled CSS and post that in the Stack Snippet. You shouldn't make us have to go somewhere else to run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:relative;` from `nav ul > li` add to `nav ul`.

Check below code.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 nav {
     background: #eee;
     padding: 10px;
}
 nav ul {
     display: block;
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     border-right: 1px solid #333;
     width: 33.333vw;
     position: relative;
}
 nav ul > li {
     display: block;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 10px;
}
 nav ul > li.has-children > a:after {
     content: '»';
     float: right;
}
 nav ul > li > a {
     display: block;
     padding: 8px 15px;
     transition: background-color 0.4s;
}
 nav ul > li > ul.sub-menu {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
 nav ul > li:hover > a {
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
 nav ul > li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 1.1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1.2</a></li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 1.3</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1.3.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 2.1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.1.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 2.2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3.4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 5.1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 5.2</a></li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="#">Sub 5.3</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5.3.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 5.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```